# Problems with citations using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have used LaTeX for reports in physics, but now I'm in a new field where I need citations. I'm not very savvy with LaTex in the first place, so please describe the possible solutions as simple as possible.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,oneside, twocolumn,article,9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib} **%this is what't new for me.**
\bibliographystyle{agsm} **%this is also new.** 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.6cm}{1.6cm}{*} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1cm} 
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
blah blah \citep{Deary200713}.
\bibliography{/Brugere/Julle/Skrivebord/LaTeX(artikel)/science.bib}
\end{document}
```

**Additional information:** As you can see, I write in Danish. I got the cited articles information from science direct, exported as a BibTeX format, and put the file in the same folder at my LaTeX document.

I get the messages:

> citation 'Deary200713' undefined

and

> there were undefined citations.

edit: This was solved when i compiled differently, as suggested in the comments AND changing the path of bibliography to just 'science' since the files are in the same folder.

Comment: Have you run `latex, bibtex, latex, latex` on your file?  The `\bibliography` path looks unusable; if your `.bib` file is in the same folder as your `.tex` file, just write `\bibliography{science}`.  Also, *don't* write `science.bib`, just write `science`.  I also recommend putting your `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` just before your `\bibliography{science}`.

Comment: Your code works as long as you have the bib. file in the same place as your main TeX file. Recall what @jon said, you need to latex --> bibtex --> latex --> latex when you build/compile your document. You can fix that on your TeXeditor options (i.e., in the quick build).

Answer (score 2):

The bibliography style `agsm` is part of the `harvard` citation package. If you want to use it with the `natbib` citation management package, you can certainly do so; just be sure to load the `har2nat` package as well. The `har2nat` package "translates" some of the `harvard`-based commands encountered in `agsm.bst` into `natbib`-equivalent commands.

Of course, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on your document to get all references in the bibliography and all citations (which are, for all practical purposes, cross-references to items in the bibliography) sorted out.

As an added bonus of loading both `natbib` and `har2nat`, the `hyperref` package works perfectly with this combination.